# Which is the most well-known Batman logo

Tags: dc, batman

Over the years there have been many different versions of the Batman logo (in terms of design). So I would like to know which is the most popular or well-known batman logo?

Please cite sources as to why that logo would be the most well-known or popular?

EDIT: For the purposes of this question, the term "popular" could be construed as the one used or featured most often.

Comment: I think this question is too broad or too subjective to be responded. I can tell you, though, that the logo with the bat in a yellow oval was a request from the editors. It was the way they had to be able to register it, since shape or silhouettes of animals (such as a bat) can't be registered, patented, etc.

Comment: Yeah I’m not clear how you can meaningfully judge how famous a logo is, much less determine reasons for fame.

Comment: "Most famous batman logo" is definitely opinion-based.  It'll change depending on which set of fans you're asking, and what series they like best.  Sorry, but I'm afraid I'm going to have to vote to close.

Comment: BWT, in Frank Miller's DKR Batman suit starts with that logo (request of the editors, since it was the "official" Batman logo). Miller managed to change it, without them noticing in the middle of the story. That doesn't mean is more famous, or more recognizable or anything. It was just a preference of using the trademarketed/copyrighted logo. This can tell you that there is not one logo that might out stand among the rest.

Comment: If you could edit to add a specific criteria for how to determine which is the most famous (e.g. most official appearances, etc.), I'd vote to reopen, but as it is, I agree this is too broad/subjective.

Comment: I did a slight edit so that the question isn't as opinion-based. Not sure if it's enough, though.

Comment: Even post-edit, this doesn't seem like a good fit for this site.  'Featured' in what sense?  Because my six-year old's batman underwear has at least two different logos, and a number of DC's non-batman comics have a bat-themed logo in the corner (or had) the same way many Marvel comics featured Spiedy's silhouette. The most well-known logo to an octogenarian would be one from 60-70 years ago, while Generation X knows the 'yellow circle' one.  I could go on, but the point is this question is EXTREMELY OVERLY BROAD, and will likely never get a real, definitive answer.

Comment: Narrowing it down to comics might help, but only just in reducing the scope.  Further narrowing it down to which logo is used most often in more series would also help, but would suffer from being incredibly difficult, if not impossible, to measure without some sort of algorithm for measuring logo appearances.

Comment: @All: Thanks for your views :)

Answer (score 2):

I just did a quick google image search for "Batman Logo". There does seem to be one that stands as the majority.

https://www.google.com/search?q=batman+logo&sa=X&es_sm=91&biw=1265&bih=811&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ei=D05FVK78A9DKggTEpoHIAg&ved=0CB0QsAQ

Comment: There is a good amount of results in that link. Do you want to at least name or describe the one you are talking about?

Comment: He's referring to the 1964 "yellow ellipse" version; http://logoshistory.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/batman-logo-history.html

Comment: @Richard, that would be my guess, but I thought that good answers provided an answer here, "in-site", not somewhere else after following a link. Also, I think that this answer is very subjective. If the googled term was "dark knight" instead of "batman", the results would favor the logo of Nolan's Batman trilogy. I'm not complaining that he just posted a link, but I thought that at least he should interpret his results, and commit to a cleared answer.

Comment: @Deion - I'd answer it if I could be bothered but there's really no point. Zibbobz has hit the nail on the head that without an objective measure, how do you determine "popular"?

Comment: @Richard: Thanks for the link. I think `Batman Returns (1992)` logo is the most popular one.